# Angular 4 material chips placeholder not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui, angular-material2

I was trying to implement angular mat-chip with selectable and removable options. But issue is the placeholder move to top at the time of loading. i m not sure what wrong i am doing on code. Please someone help me to fix this issue.

Added GIF below

[image]
 my code is

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(keyword)">
      {{keyword}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="Keywords"
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" />
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

and **ts** is

```
  visible: boolean = true;
  selectable: boolean = true;
  removable: boolean = true;
  addOnBlur: boolean = true;
  separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];
  keywords= [];   // At time load i need this to be empty


public add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    let input = event.input;
    let value = event.value;
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
        this.keywords.push(value.trim());
    }
    if (input) {
        input.value = '';
    }
}

public remove(keyword: any): void {
    let index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);
    if (index >= 0) {
        this.keywords.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

i used same code which given on material document but only change i done is instead of loading array values i am passing empty array at the time load. Please someone help me to fix this issue

Comment: I have spent the last hour and a half on the exact same issue.  Hoping someone solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Angular from 4.4.X to Latest 5.2.2. Issue got fixed. Seems Angular Bug.

Answer (score 7):

its an issue with the keywords spelling in ts file. you have defined it as

```
  keyowords = [];
```

And the name you are referring to in the html file is keywords. Change the name in ts file to

```
keywords = [];
```

This is working  stackblitz code for the same :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtti3v?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.html

Comment: Apologies i did typo error in the question, but in my code i have proper spelling for keywords

Comment: tried again today with your stackblitz code but no luck :-/

Comment: Verify you have the latest version of angular & angular material.It's hard to see from your gif, but does the element have focus on startup? If so, see what you can do to avoid this.